# Replace placeholder with format function in python3

Tags: python-3.x, format, placeholder

```
python3
width=4
' {:>%d} ' %width
' {:>4} '
width=8
' {:>%d} ' %width
' {:>8} '
```

I want to get the above effect with format function in python3.

```
width=4
' {:>%d} '.format(width)
' {:>%{0}} '.format(width)
```

None of them can get `' {:>4} '` with format function.

```
' :>%{0} '.format(width)
' :>%4 '
```

How to get the string `' {:>4} '`  instead of `' :>%4 '` with format function?
I don't like the expression:

```
>>> '{' + ' :>%{0} '.format(width) + '}'
'{ :>%4 }'
```

Comment: This kinda feels like an XY-problem because the string you are producing by itself is used as a string-format. What are you doing with that resulting string? there might a better way to get your final result

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> '{{ :>%{0} }} '.format(width)
'{ :>%4 } '
```